# How do I get ETA in labels of section?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, geopoints

What im trying to do is get the Eta in the section footer for every store that is on the tableview

my tableview cells shows the store by the distance from how far they are from your current location(don't exactly by what unit of measure) but what im trying to do is show the stores in the Tableview by their ETA instead of their distance.

the data used to populate the cells in my Tableview is from cloud Firstore and im  using GeoPoint to plot the coordinates to assist in calibration of the location

How would I be able to set up the Eta for store in the footer

the results of what im getting currently are on the Left, and the results of what im trying to get are on the **right** of the image

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class StoreViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var startDate: NSDate!
    var traveledTime: Double { return NSDate().timeIntervalSince(startDate as Date) }

    var stores: [Stores] = []
    var groupedStoreItems: [String: [Stores]] = [:]
    var storeSectionTitle: [String] = []

    var selectedStore: StoreList!

    @IBOutlet weak var storeTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Get current position
        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: locations.last!.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)

        // Get destination position
        let destinationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(selectedStore.location.latitude, selectedStore.location.longitude)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)

        // Create request
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = sourceMapItem
        request.destination = destinationMapItem
        request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculate { response, error in
            if let route = response?.routes.first {
                print("Distance: \(route.distance), ETA: \(route.expectedTravelTime)")
            } else {
                print("Error!")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension StoreViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return storeSectionTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let stores = storeSectionTitle[section]
        return groupedStoreItems[stores]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let storeInfoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreInfoCell") as! StoreInfoCell

        let stores = storeSectionTitle[indexPath.section]
        let cartItemsToDisplay = groupedStoreItems[stores]![indexPath.row]
        storeInfoCell.configure(withStoreItems: storeItemsToDisplay.information)

        return storeInfoCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let storeHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoreHeader") as! StoreHeader

        let headerTitle = storeSectionTitle[section]
        storeHeader.storeName.text = "\(headerTitle)"

        return storeHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? { 
        let distanceFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DistanceFooter") as! DistanceFooter

        let store = storeSectionTitle[section]
        let getEta = groupedStoreItems[store]!

        let distance = cartItems[section].storeList.distanceFromUser  
        distanceFooter.etaLbl.text = "\(distance)"

        return distanceFooter
    }
}


extension TimeInterval {
    struct DateComponents {
        static let formatterPositional: DateComponentsFormatter = {
            let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
            dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour,.minute,.second]
            dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading
            return dateComponentsFormatter
        }()
    }
    var positionalTime: String {
        return DateComponents.formatterPositional.string(from: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class StoreList {
    var id: String
    var storeName: String
    var category: String
    var descriptionLbl: String

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var distanceFromUser: Double

    init(id: String,
         storeName: String,
         category: String,
         descriptionLbl: String,
         location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        self.id = id
        self.storeName = storeName
        self.category = category
        self.descriptionLbl = descriptionLbl
        self.location = location
        self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))!
        print("look here!", self.distanceFromUser)
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let storeName = dictionary["storeName"] as? String ?? ""
        let category =  dictionary["category"] as? String ?? ""
        let descriptionLbl =  dictionary["description"] as? String ?? ""

        let geoPoint = dictionary["location"] as! GeoPoint
        let latitude = geoPoint.latitude
        let longitude = geoPoint.longitude

        let location =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)


        self.init(id: id,
                  name: name,
                  storeName: storeName,
                  category: category,
                  descriptionLbl: descriptionLbl,,
                  location: location)
    }

}
```

---

```
class Stores {

    var storeList : StoreList!

    init(storeList: StoreList) {

        self. storeList = storeList
    }

}
```

---

```
class StoreInfoCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLbl: UILabel!


    func configure(withStoreItems storeItems: StoreList) {
        categoryLbl.text = "\(storeList.category"
        productQty.text = "\(storeList.descriptionLbl)"

    }
}
```

Update:

im trying to use the below code in the viewForFooter to get a more accurate location for every store in their footerCell. Because I noticed `let distance` puts the stores by an inaccurate distance from what is set in my cloud Firestore

```
let store = storeSectionTitle[section]
let getEta = groupedStoreItems[store]!

let distance = cartItems[section].storeList.distanceFromUser  
distanceFooter.etaLbl.text = "\(distance)"
```

Comment: ETA depends on lots of other params which u wont be having access. You can use apples API to calculate ETA. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455127/calculate-distance-and-eta-from-maps-in-swift)

Comment: just updated my code with the link that you sent in your comment.Right now it shows "ClLocationManager.." in the etaLbl of the footer currently. how would I be able to change that to show the ETA time instead. I thin that keeping distanceFromUser over using Location in ```let destinationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(selectedStore.location.latitude, selectedStore.location.longitude)``` would work better in its place since its already giving me the results for how far I am from a store in meters or feet

Comment: The eta calculation works as expected, but you're assigning `        self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))!
` to the etaLbl. Firstly the distance(from:) will return the distance between two coordinates in a straight line not taking roads or elevation difference into account. Secondly you're force unwrapping an optional, don't. The locationmanager is not guaranteed to have a location at the time you ask and will crash often. You should assign  route.expectedTravelTime to etaLbl

Comment: @AndreasM im trying to modify my code to make it work but the results but im not able to calibrate it correctly to work. what would be the best method to make it work with ```route.expectedTravelTime```?